# Turn two selects into just one select

Tags: asp.net

I want join string query SQL and string query to one string.

This my query

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT([Name]), Id FROM Kategori WHERE id IN ('3025', '3003', '3006', '3004') ORDER BY [Name] DESC";

DataTable dth = conn.GetDataTable(sql);

string sqlcount = "SELECT DISTINCT([Name]), Id FROM Kategori WHERE id IN ('3025', '3003', '3006', '3004') OR ParentKategori_Id IN ('3025', '3003', '3006', '3004') ORDER BY [Name] DESC";

DataTable rc = conn.GetDataTable(sqlcount);

int rowhasil = rc.Rows.Count + row;

foreach (DataRow dr in dth.Rows)
{
    worksheet.Cell(row, 1).Value = dr["Name"].ToString();
    worksheet.Cell(row, 1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
    row++;

    string query = "SELECT [Name], [id] FROM Kategori WHERE [TYPE] = '2' AND ParentKategori_Id = " + dr["Id"].ToString() + "";

    DataTable dtd = conn.GetDataTable(query);

    foreach (DataRow drd in dtd.Rows)
    {
        worksheet.Cell(row, 1).Value = "      " + drd["Name"].ToString();
        row++;
    }
}
```

[I want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW7uU.png)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that allows the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. For example, you can execute multiple select statements in one shot. This feature is disabled by default. It can be enabled by adding the `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` pair to your connection string. [Look at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/multiple-active-result-sets-mars).